# MySQL joins where one field has surrounding tags to be stripped

Tags: mysql, tags, left-join

I have two MySQL tables, `articoli` and `tabtranslations`, and the join between them should be trivial

```
SELECT CodArt, Translation FROM articoli LEFT JOIN tabtranslations ON articoli.CodArt = tabtranslations.Chiave
```

BUT, while `articoli.CodArt` ha simple strings (`A001`, `BS15`, etc..), field `tabtranslations.Chiave` is filled with surronding tags like `<CODART>A001</CODART>`, `<CODART>BS15</CODART>` thus overcomplicating joins - and I cannot modify it...

Well, is there a way I can solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: does it ONLY have `<CODART></CODART>` or can the tags be anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty soulution would be like this:

```
SELECT CodArt, Translation
FROM
  articoli LEFT JOIN tabtranslations
  ON CONCAT('<CODART>', articoli.CodArt, '</CODART>') = tabtranslations.Chiave
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but maybe this will work?

```
SELECT CodArt, Translation
FROM articoli
LEFT JOIN tabtranslations ON tabtranslations.Chiave LIKE '%' + articoli.CodArt + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case 'CODART' isn't the only possible tag, you may want to use `REGEXP` in the join predicate, like so:

```
select *    
  from codart c     
    left join tabtranslations t       
      on t.chiave REGEXP CONCAT('<.*>', c.codart, '</.*>');
```

Here is a sample fiddle for you to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6c04/1